# Rails scoped validation with multiple booleans

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

### Summary:

I need to validate uniqueness of two columns given four other columns as scope:

```
validates :preference, uniqueness: { scope: [:voter_id, :term_id, :in_transaction, :transaction_destroy], message: 'must not have the same preference as another vote' }
validates :candidate,  uniqueness: { scope: [:voter_id, :term_id, :in_transaction, :transaction_destroy], message: 'can only be voted for once' }
```

This is to ensure only unique preferences and candidates for the same voter, in the same term, and within the same transaction states.

The problem is, `in_transaction` and `transaction_destroy` are booleans, meaning rails validations do not work.

How can I write a workaround?

---

### Background:

I'm working on an STV Election backend.

The entirety of the project is already finished -- frontend site, database, results generation, fancy animated results diff, etc.  The only thing I've been unable to do is the uniqueness validations.

With how STV works, each voter may enter a preference (int) for any number of candidates.  If their first preference gets eliminated, their vote transfers to their second preference, and so on.  All of these are stored in the `council_votes` table, with columns `voter_id`, `candidate_id`, and `preference`.

Users need to be able to swap preferences, too.  However, given the preference uniqueness constraint, individual updates break validation.  To solve this, and to prevent data loss on network timeouts, I added transactions.

The client app sends a `begin transaction` message, sends its preference changes, and finally sends a `commit` message.  During a transaction, all changes create a record with `in_transaction: true`; destroys create a record with `in_transcation: true, transaction_destroy: true`.  Committing the transaction destroys records first, then recreates the records with the correct preferences.  In the event of an error, it rolls back the changes and notifies the client.

Given how this works, there are essentially three sets of 'votes':

- normal vote
- `in_transaction` vote
- `in_transaction && transaction_destroy` vote

To prevent duplicate candidates/preferences, I must ensure they are unique across these three sets.  but given both state columns are boolean, how can I do this?

Or would it be easier to alter the schema and replace `in_transaction` and `transaction_destroy` with `transaction_state (null|create|destroy)` and scope that instead?  That seems to be a more sane option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a custom validation to check the presence existence of an existing record:

```
validate :is_new_preference

def is_new_preference
  !Item.exists?(preference: preference, voter_id: voter_id, term_id: term_id, in_transaction: in_transaction, transaction_destroy: transaction_destroy)
end
```

Comment: Aha, this should work.  I've since refactored my code to use the more sane `transaction_state` instead, so I cannot test this.  I'll mark it as the accepted answer. ^^

Answer (score 3):

You might be a state where its a bit late to fix this but this seems very brittle and prone to race conditions.

```
class Voter < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :council_votes
end

class Candidate < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :candidacies
  has_many :terms, through: :candidacies
end

class Candidacy < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: [:running, :dropped]
  belongs_to :candidate
  belongs_to :term
  validates_uniqueness_of :candidate_id, scope: :term_id
end

class Term < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :candidacies,
  has_many :candidates, through: :candidacies
end

class CouncilVote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :voter
  belongs_to :candidacy
  has_one :candidate, through: :candidacy
  has_one :term, through: :candidacy
  validates_uniqueness_of :voter_id, scope: :candidacy_id
end
```

Here we add a `candidacy` m-2-m join table between between `Candidate` and `Term`. With an enum bitmask column that lets us set the status. This means that we only need to ensure the uniqueness on two columns.

Lets add some db constraints to prevent race conditions and improve performance:

```
class AddUniqenessToCandidacy < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_index :candidacies, [:candidate_id, :term_id], unique: true
  end
end

class AddUniqenessToCouncilVote < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_index :council_votes, [:candidacy_id, :voter_id], unique: true
  end
end
```

The big difference here is the we just update the `candidacies` table when a candidate is eliminated.

```
@canditate = Canditate.find_by(name: 'Berny')
@canditate.candidacies.last.dropped! # sorry Berny
```

This works as a sort of soft delete. Instead of pulling and reinserting and that whole transactional *[Schrödingers Cat dilemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_cat) we* leave everything in place and use the `rating` column to order the results.

```
@term = Term.find_by(year: 2016)
@votes = CouncilVote.joins(:candidacy, :candidate, :term)
           .where(candidacy: { status: :running })
           .where(voter: @voter)
           .where(term: @term)
           .order(rating: :desc)
```

Comment: This code is more of a theoretical approach than actual working code - it most likely riddled with typos and is not tested.

Comment: This needs some critical features (such as bumping voters' preferences when a candidate withdraws), but it is definitely a good start.  However, it still has a uniqueness issue when swapping two `preference`s (`rating` in yours) between two candidates.  This code would actually allow duplicate `rating`s. :(